# Redirect php file to homepage nginx

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I am trying to redirect `old.php` ( including any parameters) to homepage with nginx.It should be a `301 redirect`

I tried the following rewrite(in server block) but its not working

`rewrite ^old.php(.*)$ https://www.example.com permanent;`

I also have a php location block

```
location ~* \.php$ { 
        root /var/www/example.com/public_html/www;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: your are looking for [QSA,R=301,L] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rewrite` directive is not working because URI starts with `/`. Try to replace:

```
rewrite ^old.php(.*)$ https://www.example.com permanent;
```

with:

```
rewrite ^/old.php(.*)$ https://www.example.com permanent;
```

Comment: Ahh how could i missed the `/` .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution, and there are more than one, is to replace the original old.php file with....

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
if( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "" ) { $qs=""; } else { $qs = "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; }
header("Location: https://www.example.com" . $qs)
?>
```